# Syntax - variable assignment

Tags: javascript

Let's have the following functionality:

```
function transformMatrix(a, b, c, d, e, f)
{
  this.data = [a, c, e, b, d, f, 0, 0, 1];
}

transformMatrix.prototype.inverse = function()
{
  //..
  this.data = newdata;
  return this.data;
}
```

and

```
var m1 = new transformMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20); // translate (10, 20)
```

Now, when I call

```
m1.inverse();
```

variable `m1` is changed.

But when I call

```
var m2 = m1.inverse();
```

variable `m1` is changed and such changed is copied to variable `m2`. Great!

Is there a way to assign result of `inverse` to a new variable without change of the original one?

I can do that by:

```
var m2 = m1;
m2.inverse();
```

But I would like to know, if there is some other way, without prior assignment, something like

```
var m2 = {m1}.inverse(); // incorrect syntax
```

that would not change `m1`.

Please note that functionality of `inverse` function should not be changed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object from `m1` and call the `inverse` function on that in order to avoid modifying the original object. Ideally, your `transformMatrix` constructor would be able to create a new matrix from a matrix that was passed to it. A constructor to do that would look something like this:

```
function transformMatrix(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    if(!(a instanceof transformMatrix)) { // if a, the first variable passed in, is NOT a matrix
        this.data = [a, c, e, b, d, f, 0, 0, 1];
    } else { // otherwise it is a matrix; we need to create a new matrix from its data
        this.data = [
            a.data[0],
            a.data[1],
            a.data[2],
            a.data[3],
            a.data[4],
            a.data[5],
            0,
            0,
            1,
        ]
    }
}
```

Now if you pass in an existing matrix to `transformMatrix`, it will create a *new* matrix from the passed in matrix's data. Modifying the new matrix will not affect the old one. The new syntax would look something like this:

```
var m2 = new transformMatrix(m1).reverse(); // note the new keyword, because you're creating a new object
```

`m2` will now be the reversed version of `m1`, and `m1` will not be affected.

#### Another option: the JSON hack

You have another option that is somewhat hacky, but does not require modifying your original `transformMatrix` constructor: using the JSON hack to duplicate your original matrix and then calling `reverse()` on the duplicated object. It would look like this:

```
var m2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m1)).reverse();
```

You could even include this hack in your `reverse()` function, which would wind up looking like this:

```
transformMatrix.prototype.inverse = function() {
    var newMatrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
    //..
    newMatrix.data = newdata;
    return newMatrix.data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is assignment `this.data = [a[0], a[1], ..., 0, 0, 1]` without `.data` okay? Should not that be `this.data = [a.data[0], a.data[1], ..., 0, 0, 1]` ..?

Comment: One more fix: `if (!(a instanceof transformMatrix))`